# Workaround for webkit bug on iOS5. Bug description: The content of an iframe which has a parent with -webkit-transform: scale(x), is scaled 2 times

Tags: ios5, webkit

I am having some trouble with a webkit bug [1]. Long story short, if an iframe has an ancestor with -webkit-transform: scale(x) the content of the iframe is scaled 2 times. 
The platform on which this is happening is iOS5 (both in Safari and UIWebView). I have tested on iOS4, iOS6 and the latest nightly build of webkit and I can not reproduce it there. So the issue seems to be fixed in the newer releases.

I tried the workaround described in one of the bug comments [2] and it does not fix the problem completely. In order for it to work I had to first add -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d and then inside a timeout add -webkit-transform: scale(x) to the same element. This would have been acceptable, but if any inherited property is changed in one of the iframe's ancestors, the workaround is nullified and the content scaled 2 times again.

Does anybody know any better way to work around this issue ?

Links:

[1] Link to bug : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15676

[2] Description of workaround : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15676#c10

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to resolve it this way:

```
webkit-transform: scale(x)
zoom: 1/x
```

Also you might want to have the same fix for scaling pretty much anything on Android 2.x

I still have an issue though on iOS5.1 that despite content is scaled correctly, if part of it was behind the visible viewport (under overflow: hidden), it still appears blank in scaled iframe.